# With the Sublime Text 2 SFTP plugin, when I try to save the file I get a failure (Permission denied) message. Why?

Tags: sublimetext2

I logged in fine, as I can browse the directories fine and open the files, but when I go to save I get a permission denied error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe simply you don't have the permission to write to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Mac or PC?  I had the same problem on OSX when using SFTP with XAMPP built in FTP server (so i could update local files instead of remote).

Try modifying the permissions on your XAMPP folder (CMD + I) and set EVERYONE to READ/WRITE.  Then click the cog (gear icon) and choose apply.  This will apply the permissions to all subfolders as well.

Try uploading your files again and see if you still get permission denied errors.

If doing this for a remote server, you'll have to make sure your SFTP user account is listed within an allowed group or is owner of files on your server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure you have write permissions. The easiest way to check and update is the follwing:

`ls -al` see which permissions are on your file
`sudo chmod 777 file_name` give permissions to desired file

See more about establishing permissions for an entire group of files http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-add-linux-user-with-document-root-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Take two steps:

1. check your server permission
2. make sure you local sftp-config.json

   { 
       "type": "sftp", // not ftp if port is default
   }